# Vmware cpufreq_online Error

Tags: ubuntu, cpu, vmware

I have been running ubuntu on Vmware for sometime now but recently started getting an error when I boot and I am unable to proceed any further.

I receive a black screen with the following message:

```
cpufreq_online: failed to initialize policy for cpu: 0 (-19)

[sda] Assuming drive cache: write through 
/dev/sda1: clean, 313076/1900544 files, 1786227/7601920 blocks
```

Nothing was changed within the VM prior to this happening.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I was able to solve this issue simply by Disabling "Accelerate 3d graphics" under the display settings.

I read somewhere that someone has a similar error regarding the cpu and they were able to solve it in this manner.

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks @holograms

Answer (score 2):

I got the same error.
I just change the Processor cores.
You can follow this:-
**Open the VM settings for the image.
Processor-> Number of cores per processor:- make it 2(More than 1).**

Answer (score 1):

Disabling "Accelerate 3d graphics" didn't work for me. But, I found somewhere else that I should increase the CPU core  which I did and it solved my problem

Comment: same as mine, like @R.Sutilya wrote in his answer: Open the VM settings for the image. Processor-> Number of cores per processor:- make it 2(More than 1).

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was neither the 3daccelerator, nor the number of cores per processor.
Our server is running Debian 10 and the solution that worked out for us was to disable the intel_pstate driver. Got the solution from here: [HOW TO FORCEFULLY DISABLE intel_pstate? intel_pstate is enabled on reboot even with intel_pstate=disable option in grub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52477213/how-to-forcefully-disable-intel-pstate-intel-pstate-is-enabled-on-reboot-even-w)

After executing the following commands in console as SUDO the error during boot disappeared:

1. Edit the GRUB config file:
   sudo nano /etc/default/grub
2. Append the following string to the GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT line:
   "intel_pstate=disable acpi=force"

OR add it as new line to form something like this:
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT = "quiet intel_pstate=disable acpi=force"

quiet option will not show all the information at boot.

3. Upgrade the GRUB:
   sudo update-grub
4. Restart the OS

Hope that this will help someone else to resolve this problem faster.