# Increase only one core CPU speed

Tags: cpu, frequency, numa

I would like to increase the speed of only 1 CPU core and reduce all other CPU core frequencies.
For this I have used the following steps:

1. [disabled intel_pstate and enabled acpi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52477213/how-to-forcefully-disable-intel-pstate-intel-pstate-is-enabled-on-reboot-even-w)
2. set CPU3 governor to performance and CPU0,1,2 to powersave

   ```
   $ sudo cpufreq-set -c 3 -g performance
   $ cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_governor

   powersave
   powersave
   powersave
   performance
   ```
3. changed lower and higher frequency ranges for each CPUs such that only CPU3 runs at a higher frequency:

   ```
   $ cpufreq-info | grep current
     current policy: frequency should be within 1.20 GHz and 1.50 GHz.
     current CPU frequency is 2.39 GHz.
     current policy: frequency should be within 1.20 GHz and 1.50 GHz.
     current CPU frequency is 2.55 GHz.
     current policy: frequency should be within 1.20 GHz and 1.50 GHz.
     current CPU frequency is 2.58 GHz.
     current policy: frequency should be within 1.20 GHz and 2.20 GHz.
     current CPU frequency is 2.20 GHz.
   ```

Unfortunately, I observe all CPU cores frequency remain similar, and they either all get set to the range of 800 MHz (when I set CPU governor of 1 core to powersave) or all CPU ranges get set to 2.20 GHz (when I set CPU governor of core 3 to performance).

I want to know if it is even possible to increase 1 core CPU frequency to a higher value and reduce the CPU frequency of all other CPUs? I came across [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1222372/why-do-we-have-cpus-with-all-the-cores-at-the-same-speeds-and-not-combinations-o) thread which says my laptop may be doing symmetric multiprocessing and what I am looking for is assymetric multiprocessing. I would like to ask if this can be set in BIOS or if there is another method to selectively only increase CPU frequency of one core.

Comment: Which processor you are using? Does it have 4 physical cores or 4 logical cores?